# Angular 2+: Inject real http in Tesbed

Tags: angular

I have two services: API and Cfg. API consumes a json API while Cfg provides configurations such as url, api key and so on. API receives an injected instance of Cfg and components receive an injected instance of API.

Here how it looks like:

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {
    Validators,
    FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class CfgService {

    constructor(private baseUrl: string, private assetsUrl: string) { }

    public getAPIUrl(): string {
        return this.baseUrl;
    }

    public getAssetsUrl(): string {
        return this.assetsUrl;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class APIService {
    constructor(
        public http: Http,
        public config: CfgService) {
    }
}

export function configurationProvider(
    baseUrl: string = "https://xxx.xxx/api/",
    assetsUrl: string = "assets"): CfgService {

    return new CfgService(baseUrl, assetsUrl);
}

@Component({
    template: ''
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(
        protected translate: TranslateService,
        private api: APIService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {

    }
}


describe('bob', () => {
    let comp: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: CfgService, useValue: configurationProvider("http://192.168.0.112:8282/api/") },
                APIService
            ],
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule
            ]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        });;
    }));

    it('should work', async(() => {

        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    }));

});
```

Upon execution, it fails with:

```
 bob
    ✖ should work
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) bob should work FAILED
        ZoneAwareError@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:923:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:71103:28
        invokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70578:36
        onInvokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:103:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70100:49
        invokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:397:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70577:48
        runTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70345:57
        drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:593:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70773:42
        invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:464:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70644:44
        timer@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:71720:34
        resolvePromise@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:712:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70892:40
        webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:763:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:70943:31
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to switch to Chrome. Phantomjs is known for swallowing errors. It's not possible to figure out what's wrong if there's no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

`FormsModule` doesn't contain `FormBuilder` provider. Import `ReactiveFormsModule` instead

---

**Old version:**

Move `CfgService` above before `APIService`

```
@Injectable()
export class CfgService {

  constructor(private baseUrl: string,private assetsUrl: string) {}

  public getAPIUrl(): string {
    return this.baseUrl;
  }

  public getAssetsUrl(): string {
    return this.assetsUrl;
  }
}
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  constructor(
    public http: Http,
    public config: CfgService) {
  }
}
```

or use `forwardRef` like

```
import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  constructor(
    public http: Http, 
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CfgService) public config: CfgService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question. Services and component are on different files in the real application. Sorry about that :X.

Comment: That's the full message, unfortunately.

Comment: I get `Error: No provider for TranslateService!` Where did you provide it?

Comment: Then you should import `ReactiveFormsModule` instead of `FormsModule`. `FormsModule` doesn't contain `FormBuilder` provider

Comment: That's it ! ReactiveFormsModule was the solution. Can you update your answer so I can accept it ?